# Router Router Switch causes unmount on updating route search/query strings

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my `App.js` I have a number of components wrapped in a `Switch` component from `react-router-dom`

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Loadable from "react-loadable";
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";

const Test = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./Test"),
  loading: () => <h1>LOADING....</h1>
});

const Test1 = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./Test1"),
  loading: () => <h1>LOADING....</h1>
});

const Test2 = Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./Test2"),
  loading: () => <h1>LOADING....</h1>
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute bgColour="blue" exact path="/" component={Test} />
      <ProtectedRoute bgColour="red" exact path="/1" component={Test1} />
      <ProtectedRoute bgColour="green" exact path="/2" component={Test2} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The `ProtectedRoute` component renders a `Route` component from `react-router-dom` passing in the specified `component`. It also has a HOC, which in my actual application checks the user is authenticated

### ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const withAuth = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
};

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component, bgColour, ...args }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: bgColour || "transparent" }}>
      <Route component={withAuth(component)} {...args} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

For each component, I have `alert`s setup to trigger on mount and unmount of the component. On a click on an element it updates the query string to a random number via `history.push`, however, this currently triggers an unmount, due to the `Switch` added in `App.js`, without the `Switch` there is no unmount. This is causing an issue in my application as an unmount is not desired behaviour and is causing issues with loading the correct data.

### Test.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Test() {
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    alert("MOUNTED BASE");
    return () => {
      alert("UNMOUNTED BASE");
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TEST COMPONENT BASE - BLUE</h1>
      <div
        onClick={() =>
          history.push({
            pathname: history.location.pathname,
            search: `?query=${Math.random().toFixed(2)}`
          })
        }
      >
        UPDATE QUERY STRING
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => history.push("/1")}>GO TO Next ROUTE</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I still want the functionality of the `Switch` but prevent the unmount on `history.push`, is this possible?

I have a `CodeSandbox` below to recreate this issue

[image: Edit priceless-lucy-w4r13n]

Comment: instead of withAuth returning functional component, can we try with class component, so reference stays the same in all re renders. Using arrow function/ functional component results in new reference each time

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Based on *only* the code you've provided, an issue I see is how every component the `ProtectedRoute` renders is decorated with the `withAuth` Higher Order Component. This results in a new component being created every time `ProtectedRoute` renders.

## Solution

You want to only decorate the routed components with HOCs once prior to where they are used.

Example:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ bgColour, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: bgColour || "transparent" }}>
      <Route {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
import React from "react";
import Loadable from "react-loadable";
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";
import withAuth from "..path/to/withAuth";

// Decorate components with HOCs once out here
const Test = withAuth(Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./Test"),
  loading: () => <h1>LOADING....</h1>
}));

const Test1 = withAuth(Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./Test1"),
  loading: () => <h1>LOADING....</h1>
}));

const Test2 = withAuth(Loadable({
  loader: () => import("./Test2"),
  loading: () => <h1>LOADING....</h1>
}));

// Render decorated components in App
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute bgColour="red" path="/1" component={Test1} />
      <ProtectedRoute bgColour="green" path="/2" component={Test2} />
      <ProtectedRoute bgColour="blue" path="/" component={Test} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit router-router-switch-causes-unmount-on-updating-route-search-query-strings]